# is there a command line to create EmbeddedDocument in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

**is there a command line to create EmbeddedDocument in a rails project**

```
rails generate model MyModelClass filed:string
```

from the above command line, it will create a Document type of class, and call mongodb to create a MyModelClass collection.

so how about if i want to have a EmbeddedDocument class?? 
is there an command line? or i have to manually create empty file and input text to do it by myself?

Thanks.